# Não foi possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal

Tags: java, linux, java-8, rmi

Formatei recentemente meu computador e estou tendo problemas para executar meus programas java.

Estou usando linux mint e as configurações são as seguintes:

java -version

```
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
```

echo $PATH

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
```

echo $JAVA_HOME

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

e o $CLASSPATH está vazio.

Consigo compilar os programas numa boa e gerar os arquivos .class, mas quando executo o comando java Servidor sempre obtenho o erro a seguir:

> Erro: Não foi possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal
>   Servidor

O que devo fazer para conseguir executar meus programas através do terminal?

O comando que uso no shell é:

```
 ~$javac *.java
 ~$java Servidor
```

A classe que estou tentando executar é a seguinte :

Servidor.java

```
    package helloWorld;

    import java.rmi.Remote;
    import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
    import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
    import java.rmi.RemoteException;
    import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

    public class Servidor implements InterfaceObjeto{

    // A chamada do construtor serve para criar os stubs
    public Servidor() {} 

    public String sayHello(){
        return "Hello, World RMI";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try{

            // cria e exporta o objeto remoto
            Servidor objeto = new Servidor();
            InterfaceObjeto stub = (InterfaceObjeto) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject( objeto, 0);

            // registra o objeto com rmi registry
            Registry registro = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            registro.bind("interfaceObjeto", stub);

            System.err.println("Servidor pronto");

        }   catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Server exception: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

InterfaceObjeto.java

```
package helloWorld;

import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface InterfaceObjeto extends Remote{
    public String sayHello() throws RemoteException;
}
```

Cliente.java

```
package helloWorld;

import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

public class Cliente {

    private Cliente(){}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String host = (args.length < 1) ? null : args[0];

        try{

            Registry registro = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(host);
            InterfaceObjeto stub = (InterfaceObjeto)     registro.lookup("InterfaceObjeto");
            String resposta = stub.sayHello();
            System.out.println("resposta: " + resposta);

        } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Client exception: " +  e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

Quando executo o arquivo através do netbeans recebo os seguinte erro:

```
Server exception: java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: helloWorld.InterfaceObjeto
```

Comment: adicionei lá :)

Comment: Não há nenhum import para `InterfaceObjeto`. Verifique se esta classe está sendo compilada também. Se ela não for encontrada, seu código não vai executar.

Comment: Mas InterfaceObjeto está no mesmo pacote da classe Servidor, ainda assim é necessário fazer o import?

Comment: Não. Então o problema não está nessa classe. Por favor, adicione todas as classes envolvidas, como a interface citada.

Comment: ja adicionei! Pode ser sim problema nas classes, to aprendendo a usar o rmi ainda, mas não vejo onde está o problema

Comment: rodei um outro programa que nao usa RMI aqui pelo shell usando os comandos javac e java e eles estao funcionando normalmente...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9542464/5524514

Comment: Poste por favor a linha de comando em que você executa sua app.

Comment: já pus. Mas não tem nada de mágico eh só um javac e um java ...

Comment: Já olhou o link que postei?

Comment: Sim.. eu fiz a classe Servidor extender UnicastRemoteObject e funcionou, agora eu consigo executar através do netbeans! Mas na linha de comando nada ainda..

Comment: Certamente está faltando alguma coisa no seu classpath. Você consegue obter a linha de comando que o netbeans está usando pra executar a sua app?